# How to remove button padding of setBackgroundTintList()

Tags: android, android-layout, button, android-linearlayout, padding

I try to simulate selector xml(first button) by java (second button).

Let's say i have this `onCreate()` java code in `MainActivity.java`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button secondButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonJavaSelector);
    int[][] hole_states = new int[][] {

            new int[]{android.R.attr.state_pressed},
            new int[]{}
    };
    int[] hole_colors = new int[] {
            ContextCompat.getColor(this, android.R.color.white),
            ContextCompat.getColor(this, android.R.color.holo_green_light)
    };
    ColorStateList holeStateList = new ColorStateList(hole_states, hole_colors);
    //secondButton.setBackgroundColor(this.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_light));
    secondButton.setBackgroundTintList(holeStateList);
    secondButton.setHighlightColor(Color.RED);
}
```

Then `activity_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.blogspot.diannaoxiaobai.tmptesting.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_sign_in"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/yes_part"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonXmlSelector"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/button_ripple_light"
                android:text="Cancel (Xml Selector)"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_light" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/no_part"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonJavaSelector"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Sign In (Java Selector)"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_light" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And then `drawable/button_ripple_light.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@android:color/white" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_green_light" />
</selector>
```

The output screenshot:

[image]

If i pressed both buttons, both able to become white color:

[image]

But i don't want the padding around the 2nd button. I searched many answers in S/O, they always suggest change background color to remove (Someone said it's shadow, not padding). So i uncomment this line in `MainActivity.java` above (Note that i set red color here):

```
secondButton.setBackgroundColor(this.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_light));
```

Now the padding no longer exist, but nothing happen(i.e. become white) when i press second button:

[image]

setBackgroundColor() to remove padding doesn't works correctly. What should i do to remove second button padding in this case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
    StateListDrawable holeStateList = new StateListDrawable();
    holeStateList.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_pressed}, new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(this,
            android.R.color.white)));
    holeStateList.addState(new int[]{}, new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(this,
            android.R.color.holo_green_light)));

    secondButton.setBackground(holeStateList);
```